# I am using Planing to use sonar 7.9 in UAT enviornment on CentOS-7 but facing some issue while starting sonar-7.9

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting below error while starting sonarqube
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

```
2020.01.03 10:31:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory 
/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/temp
2020.01.03 10:31:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2020.01.03 10:31:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, 
logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/sonarqube/sonarqube
-7.9.1/elasticsearch]: /sonarqube/sonarqube-7.9.1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on2020.01.03 10:31:26 INFO  app[]
Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will l 
likely be removed in a future release.
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
2020.01.03 10:31:26 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 
2020.01.03 10:31:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2020.01.03 10:31:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
FATAL StatusLogger Interrupted before Log4j Providers could be loaded.
java.lang.InterruptedExceptionjava.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:317)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.lazyInit(ProviderUtil.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ProviderUtil.hasProviders(ProviderUtil.java:108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.unit.ByteSizeValue.<clinit>(ByteSizeValue.java:39)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.<clinit>(NetworkService.java:57)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSettings.<clinit>(TransportSettings.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.newPluginService(TransportClient.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.buildTemplate(TransportClient.java:135)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.<init>(TransportClient.java:277)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl$MinimalTransportClient.<init> 
    (EsConnectorImpl.java:103)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.buildTransportClient(EsConnectorImpl.java:89)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getTransportClient(EsConnectorImpl.java:74)
    at org.sonar.application.es.EsConnectorImpl.getClusterHealthStatus(EsConnectorImpl.java:61)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkStatus(EsManagedProcess.java:88)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.checkOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:73)
    at org.sonar.application.process.EsManagedProcess.isOperational(EsManagedProcess.java:58)
    org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:201)
 org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:258)
 ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the 
 classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the consol
 e...
 <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

> ```
> Java -version
>     Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on
>     openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
>     OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
>     OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
> ```

Need help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The error that's causing Sonarqube to exit is `Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'`. This indicates you have a JAVA_OPTIONS (or command-line parameter) - set to `+XX:UseParNewGC`. As `UseParNewGC` was dropped in Java 10, this option can be safely removed.

Comment: Hi mc1arke,
Thanks for your help. My error gone and es.log is generated after applying your suggestion. 

But,

Still I am not able to start sonarqube. Now there is issue in elastic search. I have paste Log below.

Comment: @UnixLinuxMan I can't see your additional log. Where have you included it?